# Cryptographic Arithmetic Toolbox/Software

Tags: finite-field

This term I have many cryptography courses treating finite fields.
I was wondering if there is any good software that could help doing basic operations in galois fields etc.
I already googled but found nothing appropriate.

What I would need:
A tool/software that can calculate in arbitrary galois fields `gf(p^n)`

(+,-,*,/,gcd, inverse)

In addition to that I would need a function to generate an irreducible polynomial for a given field. (parameters could get big e.g. 2^100)

I already considered matlab generating a irreducible polynomial for gf(2^103), but computation takes too long.

Do you have any recommendations and do you know any good programs for calculation in finite fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but reference requests are off-topic. However, [Sage](http://www.sagenb.org) is a popular and free tool.

Comment: As DrLecter says, this question will probably be closed as off-topic. My recommendation would be MAGMA.

Comment: okay, but where would have been the right place to ask?

Comment: Discussion of mathematical software is on-topic at Math.SE, as are reference requests (if that's an issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sage or MATLAB. Among the two sage is free and uses python as the programming language.

Comment: Looks very promising, I will give it a try, thx

Comment: Sage seems to be the perfect tool for this. The docs belonging to the topic can be found under http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/finite_rings/constructor.html